# Updating list object based on key - LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

This is my List object

```
List<MemObject>
                   {
                       new MemObject
                           {Serial = 1, ErrorCode = "ABC", ModifedAt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 10, 10, 30)},
                       new MemObject
                           {Serial = 1, ErrorCode = "ABD", ModifedAt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 10, 10, 30)},
                       new MemObject
                           {Serial = 1, ErrorCode = "ABC", ModifedAt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 10, 10, 30)},
                       new MemObject
                           {Serial = 1, ErrorCode = "ABC", ModifedAt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 15, 10, 10, 30)},
                   };
```

I want to update ModifiedAt field by incrementing time with one second for every 2, 3, .. n record which has same Serial, ErrorCode.

How can this be done in linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update each ModifiedAt record. You may have to do Count(...) - 1 if you do not want to include the updated object in the count of records.

```
memObjects.ForEach(x => x.ModifiedAt.AddSeconds(memObjects.Count(y => y.Serial == x.Serial && y.ErrorCode == x.ErrorCode)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is as close to a single linq statement as I can get. It does work though.

```
    public void IncrementTime(int serial, string errorCode)
    {
        var matchObjects = _memObjects.Where(x => x.Serial == serial && x.ErrorCode == errorCode).ToList();

        matchObjects.ForEach(x => x.ModifedAt = x.ModifedAt.AddSeconds(
                                    matchObjects.Count(y => matchObjects.IndexOf(y) < matchObjects.IndexOf(x))
                             ));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
public void IncrementTime(int serial, string errorCode)
{
    _memObjects.Where(x => x.Serial == serial && x.errorCode == errorCode)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.ModifiedAt = x.ModifiedAt.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will not really help you here.  It isn't meant to be used used to update collections but searching through them.  You shouldn't expect any more from that.  Used correctly, you can group your items and update the items based on your requirements.

```
// group the MemObjects by Serial and ErrorCode that has more than 1 occurrences
var query = list.GroupBy(mo => new { mo.Serial, mo.ErrorCode })
                //.Where(g => g.Count() > 1); // O(n)
                .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any()); // O(1)

// make the updates
foreach (var group in query)
{
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var mo in group)
    {
        mo.ModifedAt += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i++);
    }
}
```